# Light waves confusion

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

This may be a simple question but its really confusing me, I cant find answer for it still now, please help me. My doubt is what do we actually mean by *amplitude of a light wave* (an EM-wave), is it wave produced in *electric field or magnetic field* ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both. In the simplest case of a wave traveling through an isotropic medium (vacuum, air, water, glass), the electric field strength and magnetic field strength are proportional to each other: $E = cB$. Here, $E$ is the electric field strength, $B$ is the magnetic field strength, and $c$ is the speed of light. If you know one field strength, you know the other one.

Comment: Thank you very much Mark H